# Postman identical request not working in angularjs http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, http, postman

I have this postman request but some how its angularjs equivalent is not working

I want to get the response for the exact request in post man as follows.
In postman Its giving me what I need but can't make it work in angular

```
var settings = {
      "async": true,
      "crossDomain": true,
      "url": "http://197.157.93.110/Apiv1/token",
      "method": "POST",
      "headers": {
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "postman-token": "c76c4b6a-9a69-23dd-0171-8e6cbacd7944",
        "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      },
      "data": {
        "grant_type": "password",
        "UserName": "user1",
        "Password": "password"
      }
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
```

my angular code looks like this

```
services.factory('documentService', ['$http', function($http){
            return {
                    getToken:function(grant_type,user,password){
                        return $http({
                                method:"POST",
                                url:"http://197.156.93.110/Apiv1/token",
                                headers: {
                                            "cache-control": "no-cache",
                                            "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                                  },
                                data: {
                                    "grant_type": grant_type,
                                    "UserName": user,
                                    "Password": password
                                  }         
                        });
                    }
                ,
```

I get error Bad Request with code 400

Am using it later at my code by calling the promise like this

```
documentService.getToken("password","user1","password").success(function(token){
        $scope.access_token=token.access_token;
        $scope.userName=token.userName;
        $scope.token_type=token.token_type;
        $scope.message={"message":"success"};
                $interval(function () {
                    $scope.message = "";
                }, 10000);
                //call get documents if only access token is success


    }).error(function(err){
        $scope.message=err;
        $interval(function () {
            $scope.message = "";
        }, 10000);
    });
```

Comment: tnks, it says Bad request

Comment: Have you compared the requests in the network inspector of your browser?

Comment: Nop,how can I do that ,Let me try ,But the first request is on postman and seconed is on browser /my code/

Comment: bad request is something which you get when you are sending the parameters wrong, try to run a fiddler and check whether the parameters you sent here and postman are same

Comment: Yes am looking network inspector now and it says no params on the request ,What do you think is the problem at least it should mention the params i have sent

Answer (score 0):

In the code you've provided, you have initiated the ajax call and provided a callback function for the Postman block-- that is, what should be done when the ajax call succeeds and returns data. You haven't provided this for the AngularJS example.

$http is a promise-based package. You can see from the Angular documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) under General Usage that $http should be invoked with a .then() handler, as such:

```
var settings = {
   //POST settings
}
$http(settings)
.then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
    console.log(response);
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
    console.log(response);
  });
```

Comment: I have done that in the rest of my codeusing .success().error().  but here the promise should return something  But here the response of the promise is Bad request so I want to solve that ,see edit how am using it later

Answer (score 0):

Just ttransforming the request and deleting the cache control on the header worked for me

final code

```
services.factory('documentService', ['$http', function($http){
return {
        getToken:function(grant_type,user,password){
            return $http({
                    method:"POST",
                    url:"http://197.156.93.110/Apiv1/token",
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, 
                     transformRequest: function(obj) {
                        var str = [];
                        for(var p in obj)
                        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                        return str.join("&");
                    },
                    data: {
                        "grant_type": "password",
                        "UserName": "user1",
                        "Password": "password"
                      }         
            });
        }
    ,
```